# sending email from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, smtpclient

May someone please assist me in correcting this error that occurs when I try to send an email from the contact us page of my website

[image]

My code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim msg As New MailMessage()
    msg.From = New MailAddress(email.Text)
    msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress("test@milcoxmanor.com"))
    msg.Subject = subject.Text
    msg.Body = Message.Text
    'Try
    '    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = " smtp server name or address "
    '    SmtpMail.Send(msg)
    'Catch ex As HttpException
    '    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString())
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString())
    'End Try
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("milcoxmanor.com", 25)
    smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("test@milcoxmanor.com", "12345")
    smtp.Send(msg)


End Sub
Protected Sub ClearFields()
    fname.Text = " "
    lname.Text = " "
    email.Text = " "
    subject.Text = " "
    message.Text = " "
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What error? You need to give us the full text of the error and what line is causing it.

Comment: The error is what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, you're probably missing:

```
 Imports System.Net.Mail
```

at the top of the file

Comment: `using` is C# ... they are using VB.NET so it would be `Imports`

Comment: Compilation Error

. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30561: 'MailMessage' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Web.Mail, System.Net.Mail'.

Source Error:


Line 35: 
Line 36:     Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Line 37:        Dim msg As New MailMessage()
Line 38:         msg.From = New MailAddress(email.Text)
Line 39:         msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress("test@milcoxmanor.com"))

Comment: @user2307970: remove the import for System.Web.Mail.  That namespace is deprecated.

Comment: thanx it looks like Iam getting somwewhere